# Incremental count in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, counter

I am working with a Raiser's Edge database using SQL Server 2005. I have written SQL that will produce a temporary table containing details of direct debit instalments. Below is a small table containing the key variables for the question I'm going to ask, with some fictional data:

```
Donor_ID    Instalment_ID    Instalment_Date    Amount 
1234        1111             01/01/2011         £5.00
1234        1112             01/02/2011         £0.00
1234        1113             01/03/2011         £5.00
1234        1114             01/04/2011         £5.00
1234        1115             01/05/2011         £0.00
1234        1116             01/06/2011         £0.00
2345        2111             01/01/2011         £0.00
2345        2112             01/02/2011         £5.00
2345        2113             01/03/2011         £5.00
2345        2114             01/04/2011         £0.00
2345        2115             01/05/2011         £0.00
2345        2116             01/06/2011         £0.00
```

As you will see, some of the values in the Amount column are £0.00. This can occur when a donor has insufficient funds in their account, for example.

What I'd like to do is write a SQL query that will create a field containing an incremental count of consecutive £0.00 payments that resets after a non-£0.00 payment or after a change in Donor_ID. I have reproduced the above data below, with the field I'd like to see.

```
Donor_ID    Instalment_ID    Instalment_Date    Amount    New_Field
1234        1111             01/01/2011         £5.00     
1234        1112             01/02/2011         £0.00     1
1234        1113             01/03/2011         £5.00
1234        1114             01/04/2011         £5.00
1234        1115             01/05/2011         £0.00     1
1234        1116             01/06/2011         £0.00     2
2345        2111             01/01/2011         £0.00     1
2345        2112             01/02/2011         £5.00
2345        2113             01/03/2011         £5.00
2345        2114             01/04/2011         £0.00     1
2345        2115             01/05/2011         £0.00     2
2345        2116             01/06/2011         £0.00     3
```

To help clarify what I'm looking for, I think what I'm looking to do would be similar to a winning streak field on a list of a football team's results. For example:

```
Opponent     Score    Winning_Streak
Arsenal      1-0      1
Liverpool    0-0
Swansea      3-1      1
Chelsea      2-1      2
Fulham       4-0      3
Stoke        0-0      
Man Utd      1-3
Reading      2-1      1
```

I've considered various options, but have made no progress. Unless I've missed something obvious, I think that a solution more advanced than my current SQL programming level might be required.

Answer (score 1):

If I am thinking about this problem correctly, I believe that you want a row number when the Amount is 0.00 pounds.

```
Select 0 as As InsufficientCount
       , Donor_ID
       , Installment_ID
       , Amount
From [Table]
Where Amount > 0.00
Union
Select Row_Number() Over (Partition By Donor_ID Order By Installment_ID) 
       , Donor_ID
       , Installment_ID
       , Amount
From [Table]
Where Amount = 0.00
```

This union select should only give you 'ranks' where the Amount equals 0.

Comment: This will not reset the streak to 0 when a payment gets made. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a571f/28

Comment: The streak only increments when the transaction = 0.00, which is what @user2182597 was describing.  My query only returns 0 if the transaction amount is greater than 0.  Maybe it should return NULL or an empty string.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a571f/28 shows that Donor_ID has 3 transactions where the amount = 0.00 and the InsufficientCount (more appropriately 'streak') increments

Comment: Row 2345 2114 should say 1, cause row 2345 2113 resets the streak to 0. Instead it says 2.

Comment: Row 2345 2111 is the first, Row 2345 2114 is the second.  Both Transaction 2112 and 2113 have amounts > 0.

Comment: Read the question: "that resets after a non-£0.00 payment"

Comment: @flup Oh okay.  I'm sorry, you're right. I'll shut up now hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Am calling your new field `streakAmount`

```
ALTER TABLE instalments ADD streakAmount int NULL;
```

Then, to update the value:

```
UPDATE instalments
SET streakAmount =
  (SELECT 
     COUNT(*)
   FROM 
     instalments streak
   WHERE 
     streak.donor_id = instalments.donor_id 
   AND
     streak.instalment_date <= instalments.instalment_date
   AND
   (streak.instalment_date >
    -- find previous instalment date, if any exists
    COALESCE(
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(instalment_date)
        FROM
          instalments prev
        WHERE
          prev.donor_id = instalments.donor_id
        AND
          prev.amount > 0
        AND 
          prev.instalment_date < instalments.instalment_date
      )
     -- otherwise min date
     , cast('1753-1-1' AS date))
    )
  )
WHERE
  amount = 0;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a571f/18